# After recent updates USB Keyboard takes many probes before eventually working - Pi 4 & Ducky One2 Keyboard

Tags: pi-4, usb

After reloading my Pi Desktop OS, suddenly from boot up my keyboard takes many minutes (maybe at least an hour) to properly get probed and working.  This was working on 64 bit that I installed a month ago, and 32 bit that I installed about 3 weeks ago.  This current version is a freshly downloaded image as of about September 13th.
Hardware is a Raspberry pi 4 w/ 8gb of ram.  The keyboard is a Ducky One2 RGB.  Other keyboard works fine.  Ducky RGB works great on other computers.
The behavior:
I see errros in Dmesg, over and over again until eventually it will load the keyboard. This takes many minutes to finally work.  I'm litterally typing this question on the keyboard that is having issues.  Obviously I would rather not  wait an hour before using my keyboard after a reboot.

```
[  +0.488761] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 120 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.136978] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=0348, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  +0.000014] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000008] usb 1-1.3: Product: Ducky Keyboard
[  +0.000006] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd.
[  +0.008646] input: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:04D9:0348.05C8/input/input1486
[  +0.064803] hid-generic 0003:04D9:0348.05C8: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3/input0
[  +0.005693] usbhid 1-1.3:1.1: can't add hid device: -32
[  +0.000017] usbhid: probe of 1-1.3:1.1 failed with error -32
[  +0.002402] usbhid 1-1.3:1.2: can't add hid device: -32
[  +0.000014] usbhid: probe of 1-1.3:1.2 failed with error -32
[  +0.005541] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 120
[  +0.495940] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 121 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.137202] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=0348, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  +0.000035] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000021] usb 1-1.3: Product: Ducky Keyboard
[  +0.000018] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd.
[  +0.024578] usbhid 1-1.3:1.0: can't add hid device: -32
[  +0.000065] usbhid: probe of 1-1.3:1.0 failed with error -32
[  +0.005997] usbhid 1-1.3:1.1: can't add hid device: -32
[  +0.000046] usbhid: probe of 1-1.3:1.1 failed with error -32
[  +0.004486] usbhid 1-1.3:1.2: can't add hid device: -32
[  +0.000057] usbhid: probe of 1-1.3:1.2 failed with error -32
[  +0.007401] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 121
[  +0.300107] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 122 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.136997] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=04d9, idProduct=0348, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  +0.000031] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000018] usb 1-1.3: Product: Ducky Keyboard
[  +0.000017] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd.
[  +0.010784] input: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:04D9:0348.05C9/input/input1487
[  +0.065368] hid-generic 0003:04D9:0348.05C9: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3/input0
[  +0.007380] hid-generic 0003:04D9:0348.05CA: hiddev97,hidraw5: USB HID v1.11 Device [DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3/input1
[  +0.008487] input: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard System Control as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2/0003:04D9:0348.05CB/input/input1488
[  +0.062078] input: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2/0003:04D9:0348.05CB/input/input1489
[  +0.001045] input: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard Mouse as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2/0003:04D9:0348.05CB/input/input1490
[  +0.000726] input: DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.2/0003:04D9:0348.05CB/input/input1491
[  +0.001395] hid-generic 0003:04D9:0348.05CB: input,hidraw6: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [DuckyChannel International Co., Ltd. Ducky Keyboard] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3/input2
```

I'm unclear of action I can take, so I'm posing the question here.  I found one other person having this issue, though I'm unsure if they are on a Raspberrypi or not.  They simply say, "Ubuntu" with no other details.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1426289/usb-keyboard-taking-dozens-of-probes-before-being-registered/1429770#1429770

Comment: try a different keyboard

Comment: I too have a Ducky one 2 and facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

The keyboard works fine on grub menu but fails to get detected when a full kernel boots. I see a lot of probe messages that says "can't add hid device: -71"

The only thing that seems to work for me is to unplug keyboard and wait for 15 seconds before plugging it back in after booting is complete.

Also tried disabling NKRO to check if it was the source of the issue but no. same issue happens with 6KRO too